# What type of CNN will be suitable for underwater image processing?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

The primary objective (my assigned work) is to do an image segmentation for the underwater images using a convolutional neural network.  The camera shots taken from the underwater structure will have poor image quality due to severe noise and bad light exposure. In order to achieve higher classification accuracy, I want to do an automatic image enhancement for the images (see the attached file). So, I want to know, which CNN architecture will be best to do both tasks. Please kindly suggest any possible solutions to achieve the objective.

[image: See the image attached for reference]

Answer (score 1):

What do you need to segment? I'd be nice so see some labels of the segmentation.

You may not need to enhance the image, if all your dataset has that same amount of noise, the network will generalize properly.

Regarding CNNs architectures, it depends on the constraints you have with processing power and accuracy. If that is not a constrain go with something like [MaskRCNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN), check that repo as a good starting point, some results are like this:
[image]
Be mindful it's a bit of a complex architecture so inference times might be a bit too high (but it's doable on realtime depending your gpu).

Other simple architectures are FCN (Fully Convolutional Networks) with are basically your CNN but instead of fully connected layers:
[image]

You replace with with Fully Convolutional Layers:
[image]

Images taken [from HERE](http://www.micc.unifi.it/bagdanov/pdfs/FCN-presentation.pdf).

The advantage of this FCNs are that they are really easy to implement and modify since you can go with simple architectures (FCN-Alexnet), to more complex and more accurate ones (FCN-VGG, FCN-Resnet).

Also, I think you don't mention framework, there are many to choose from and it depends on your familiarly with languages, most of them you can do them with python:

- TensorFlow
- Pytorch
- MXNet

But if you are a beginner, try starting with a GUI based one, [Nvidia Digits](https://developer.nvidia.com/digits) is a great starting point and really easy to configure, it's based on Caffe so it's fairly fast when deploying and can easily be integrated with accelerators like TensorRT.

Comment: Thank you @bpinaya for your detailed reply. My project is to do automatic detection of faults in hull (main body of the ship) using CNN. I want to segment the faulty areas such as broken structures and cracks in the image. We can assume most of the pictures will be having same amount of noises.

Comment: I am a beginner to neural networks. The basic knowledge I have is how a neural network and cnn works. I have some hands on in python. As of now i am able to build a neural network for classification and regression by editing already written code according to my needs. So I am not a programming person and from core engineering field who was put incharge of doing a automation work. 

I can get a basic idea from your reply but not able to understand the full meaning because i am in a beginner level. But I will take this as a thread and try to learn from the hints.

Comment: In that case you need to start from scratch, I'll suggest you take a course regarding CNNs first, since that'll help you understand what you are coding, the best one out there might be this https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning , but then again it's paid, but it's worth it.
If you have a hard deadline try Nvidia Digits (the link I posted), install it and fine tune already trained networks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable suggestions. Since I have enough time, will start with the tutorial you have mentioned.